# Fullscreen freezes after closing JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
package sample;

import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JDesktopPane d = new JDesktopPane();
        frame.setTitle("Frame");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60));
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText("Button");
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(btn);
        frame.add(panel);
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                    System.out.println("File selected: " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
                    chooser.getFocusCycleRootAncestor().setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    chooser.getFocusCycleRootAncestor().setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(), chooser, "Browse", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code looks weird for you, but thats the only way to preserve my full screen using `GraphicsDevice`. My problem is that, when I click the cancel or open button of the JFileChooser, my screen freezes using this code `chooser.getFocusCycleRootAncestor().setVisible(false);`. How can I close the JOPtionPane using internal dialog without freezing my screen or closing the whole screen.

Comment: Why are you using JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog? This supposed to only be used with a JDesktopPane? Why can't you just use the JFileChooser's own dialog?

Comment: I am on full screen, I cant use JFileCHooser's own dialog, it will pop out outside my full screen.

Comment: The problem is, the `JOptionPane` isn't being disposed of properly, leaving the application thinking that it still has modal dialog visible...as to the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the program still thinks that there is a modal dialog open, which is restricting focus to the modal dialog...

Try changing your `chooser`'s `actionListener` to something like this...

```
chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Container parent = chooser.getParent();
        while (!(parent instanceof JOptionPane)) {
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }

        JOptionPane op = (JOptionPane) parent;
        op.setValue("done");

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
            System.out.println("File selected: " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

This basically "tricks" the `JOptionPane` into thinking that the user has selected a value (which you've actually not provided anything for) and closes the dialog, returning control back to your application

Comment: Thank you, its working now. I have a lot of issues regarding this GraphicsDevice.

Comment: Sir, i have question. This code doesnt wait until the JOptionPane window will close, it goes immediately to the next line in the code.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Any code I add after `JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog` is not run until AFTER the `actionPerformed` method calls `JOptionPane#setValue`

Answer (score 1):

you problem is not in

```
chooser.getFocusCycleRootAncestor().setVisible(false);
```

if you make these changes, your code will work flawlessly

just remove this part

```
 JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(),chooser, "Browse",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

and add this code instead

```
 chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

let me know if you have further concerns

Comment: I am using full screen, I made it JOptionPane to preserve my full screen. If I used the code you told me, it will show the JFileChooser outside my full screen.

Comment: what os are you using ? in windows 8, jdk 1.7 and it shows inside the full screen.